# Remove all values after specific one from array with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Considering a list of the days of the week converted into an array, I was able to extract the value of any of them from the array upon clicking on it.
However, I cannot find anything about how to remove all of the values following the clicked one from the array:

- for example, remove `#saturday` and `#sunday` when clicked on li with id `friday`

Please let me know if you know how to do so, and thank you all in advance for your time and attention.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="monday">Monday</li>
  <li id="tuesday">Tuesday</li>
  <li id="wednesday">Wednesday</li>
  <li id="thursday">Thursday</li>
  <li id="friday">Friday</li>
  <li id="saturday">Saturday</li>
  <li id="sunday">Sunday</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var floorIds = new Array('#monday', '#tuesday', '#wednesday', '#thursday', '#friday', '#saturday', '#sunday');

$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  var which = $(this).attr('id');
  var newFloorIds = floorIds;
  var floorPos = newFloorIds.indexOf('#'+floorId);
  newFloorIds.length  = floorPos + 1;
  console.log(newFloorIds, floorIds);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find elements position in array:

```
var elementPosition = floorIds.indexOf('#'+$(this).attr('id'));
```

Then set array length to index+1

```
floorIds.length  = elementPosition + 1; //as index are zero based
```

```js
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
var floorIds = new Array('#monday', '#tuesday', '#wednesday', '#thursday', '#friday', '#saturday', '#sunday');
  var elementPosition = floorIds.indexOf('#'+$(this).attr('id'));
  floorIds.length  = elementPosition + 1; 
  console.log(floorIds)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="monday">Monday</li>
  <li id="tuesday">Tuesday</li>
  <li id="wednesday">Wednesday</li>
  <li id="thursday">Thursday</li>
  <li id="friday">Friday</li>
  <li id="saturday">Saturday</li>
  <li id="sunday">Sunday</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help and time Milind, really appreciated.

Comment: @IVIVP: Glad it helps. And yes, this is faster than splice. Because splice creates another array element

Comment: Sorry @Milind Anantwar but if you don't mind me asking, how would you do for the result to be the very opposite of that? Say you click on `#friday`, your array only keeps the values after that, `#saturday, #sunday`?
I know it's a different question, but if you don't mind it's just to avoid posting another question about the same thing. Thank you in advance

Comment: No Problem. You can use slice here. `floorIds.slice(floorIds.indexOf('#saturday'),floorIds.length)`. However this returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object. You may want to store this in new variable for further operation :)

Comment: And would there be a way to replace saturday by the 'next one' in order to fit that into an automated function? for example, if click on tuesday, it would result to `indexOf('#wednesday')` in your example

Comment: No it wont. you can give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately that solution doesn't seem to have worked for me somehow (probably my fault for I am just getting used to javascript) though, but I'll try to find an easier alternative, for I am clearly punching above my weight here.
But once again, thank you ever so much for all of your help and time @Milind Anantwar

Comment: No Problem. Let us know if you got any further queries after giving the attempt. We will try to figure out in playground then.

Comment: Hi Milind, hope everything is fine with you. I'm sorry for yet another message but just had another question if you don't mind about your code:
as it is, the array values change (some are deleted) on a click, but how could I prevent that from happening, so that each time I click, the array initially has all of the values inside? I placed the array outside of the click function and assign it to another one, but each click still changes the original one permanently for some reason! (see edited code).
Thank you in advance Milind

Comment: You will need to create an independent copy of the array in click function. and then use it for modification. this will prevent modification to base array. Give it a go...will see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try .nextAll() function of [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).

```
$('#friday').nextAll('li').remove();
```

Comment: Thank you for a really nice and simple solution as well. I still needed to find out about how to do it from an array point of view, but I'll definitely be using this as well going further.
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice to delete the range of elements from array.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
var floorIds = new Array('#monday', '#tuesday', '#wednesday', '#thursday',  '#friday', '#saturday', '#sunday');

$('ul li').on('click', function() {
   var which = $(this).attr('id');
   var index = floorIds.indexOf('#'+which);
   var newArray = floorIds.splice(index + 1, floorIds.length - index); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to find the position of the value in the array, and then `slice` to chop off the rest beyond that index.

```js
var floorIds = new Array('#monday', '#tuesday', '#wednesday', '#thursday', '#friday', '#saturday', '#sunday');

$(function() {
  $('ul li').on('click', function() {
    var day = $(this).attr('id');
    var newArray = floorIds.slice(0, floorIds.indexOf("#"+day)+1);
    console.log(newArray);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="monday">Monday</li>
  <li id="tuesday">Tuesday</li>
  <li id="wednesday">Wednesday</li>
  <li id="thursday">Thursday</li>
  <li id="friday">Friday</li>
  <li id="saturday">Saturday</li>
  <li id="sunday">Sunday</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

*In Javascript we have a slice method for subset Array. Please do below chages*

```
 var floorIds = new Array('#monday', '#tuesday', '#wednesday', '#thursday', '#friday', '#saturday', '#sunday');
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
 var which = $(this).attr('id);
 var index = floorIds.indexOf('#'+which); //Will give the index of Element
var newArray = floorIds.slice(0, index); // Slice will provide the subset array of given indexs
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','ul li',function(){
  var array = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  var index = array.indexOf($(this).text());
array.length=index+1;
});
```

Comment: Without any explanation as to why you're recommending this particular solution or how it works exactly, it's not clear to anyone whether or not this solution will work for them. Remember, you're not just answer for the OP, but you're also answering for everyone who finds your answer when looking for a solution a similar problem they might be having.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. So the working of this solution is goes like this when the user clicks on any specific element (in this case is the list) then that element text is passed into an array.indexOf to get the index of clicked element in our array and then we reset the array to that length.